# Return Clear Form on Clicking Send

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I have a very crude PHP Contact Form I wish to give an animation effect on pressing Send. I want my form to shoot off the screen, followed by a small animation and finally the form to come back down, so far so good. My only problem is, is clearing the form on the return, does anyone now how this can be done? Any help would be massively appreciated. Here is the link to the contact form in question.

http://locodesignz.com

Problem Solved Now! Thanks guys.

Comment: You've tagged this question as a Java question. What does it have to do with Java?

Comment: We will help but for that you should post your code

Comment: I do apologise, after pressing Send I am using JS for a small animation.

Comment: Yes I can help you. This can be done using css3 and javascript

Comment: it's javascript not java.

Comment: Fantastic! Would you like me to edit my question with the current HTML markup? @zgood

Comment: clearing the form on the return. what it means?not showing form?

Comment: @LiamDavidHodnett Give me like 10-15 min to get a Fiddle together

Comment: When I say clear the form I mean clear the input data @web2students.com apologies for being a little vague

Comment: Thankyou @zgood your a life savour! Really appreciate it.

Comment: At the end of javascript, there is error, Ã¢â‚¬â€¹ remove this part, then it will work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work :

**First**: Only keep one click event attached to a button.Remove onclick="":

```
<input class="button" type="button" value="Send It" name="submit"></input>
```

**Second**: Add submit and reset to the JQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){

        $("#contact-form") .delay(1000) .animate({ height:'toggle', opacity:'toggle' }, (400));

        $("#sending-wrapper") .delay(1400) .animate({ top: '-=593' }, 400);
        $("#sending-wrapper") .delay(2400) .animate({ top: '+=593' }, 400);

        $("#thanks") .delay(4700) .animate({ top: '-=593' }, 400);
        $("#thanks") .delay(2400) .animate({ top: '+=593' }, 400);

        $("#contact-form") .delay(6600) .animate({ height:'toggle', opacity:'toggle' }, (400));

        // to reset the form data
        document.getElementById("contact").submit();
        document.getElementById("contact").reset();
    });
});
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! Thanks so much for your help @zword and thanks to everyone else also!

Comment: @LiamDavidHodnett this wont work perfectly as desired because the data of the from is being reset before it is submitted. So you wont be able to get the data on Clicking the "Send It" button.

Comment: you are right khurram.How can i make such a mistake.Ok i will edit my answer.

Comment: @LiamDavidHodnett you should see my updated answer inorder to make your page work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

After seeing your code at wesite this is my answer. If you want to just reset the data then use:

```
document.getElementById("contact").reset();
```

Write this code when the "Send It" button is clicked.
Simple enough.

**EDIT:**

I have seen there is this piece of code written on your page. Modify it to this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".button").click(function(){

        $("#contact-form") .delay(1000) .animate({ height:'toggle', opacity:'toggle' }, (400));

        $("#sending-wrapper") .delay(1400) .animate({ top: '-=593' }, 400);
        $("#sending-wrapper") .delay(2400) .animate({ top: '+=593' }, 400);

        $("#thanks") .delay(4700) .animate({ top: '-=593' }, 400);
        $("#thanks") .delay(2400) .animate({ top: '+=593' }, 400);

        $("#contact-form") .delay(6600) .animate({ height:'toggle', opacity:'toggle' }, (400));

        // to reset the form data
        document.getElementById("contact").reset();
    });
});
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Sorry @khurramhassan I'm a little new to PHP and JS, where exactly would this piece of code go? Thanks, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
$(".button").click(function(){

$("#contact-form") .delay(1000) .animate({ height:'toggle', opacity:'toggle' }, (400));

$("#sending-wrapper") .delay(1400) .animate({ top: '-=593' }, 400);
$("#sending-wrapper") .delay(2400) .animate({ top: '+=593' }, 400);

$("#thanks") .delay(4700) .animate({ top: '-=593' }, 400);
$("#thanks") .delay(2400) .animate({ top: '+=593' }, 400);

$("#contact-form") .delay(6600) .animate({ height:'toggle', opacity:'toggle' }, (400));
$("#contact")[0].reset();

});
});
```

you can replace you code with this i have added Jquery form reset to you click function

Comment: Thanks @Anthony I am afraid however that the form drops back down with the input variables still in place, I appreciate the help though!